# Is It possible to use Linux bridges on Travis-CI?

Tags: travis-ci

It seem the OpenVZ setup doesn't allow Linux bridges:

```
$ modprobe bridge
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab090.5/modules.dep: No such file or directory
The command "modprobe bridge" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Specifically, trying to use Libvirt, I get:

```
Error while activating network: Call to virNetworkCreate failed: Unable to create bridge virbr1: Package not installed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to modprobe on Travis CI, either regularly or through its Docker implementation. I ran into the same problem recently while trying to modprobe mac80211_hwsim.

I ended up using Wercker CI instead. Using their Docker implementation I was able to modprobe just fine.

http://wercker.com/

https://github.com/Robpol86/libnl/blob/3db945a/wercker.yml